# Possible to limit the size of a window (such as a browser window) to exact pixel dimensions?

Tags: window-manager, browser

Is it possible set the size of a navigator or web browser window to exact pixel dimensions in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using Compiz (installed by default) there is a Window Rules plugin that can do this.  If you need this for web development, then you will be better off with various plugins specific to each browser; otherwise you may find this helpful.

Open *CompizConfig Settings Manager*<sup>1</sup> from *System → Preferences*.  Navigate to the *Window Rules* plugin in the *Window Management* category (you'll see #1 below).  In the *Size rules* tab, add a new rule (#2), grab the criteria by clicking on the window (#3, #4).  Enter the size (you can see I previously added an example rule for Opera at 800x600), and this size will be used when matching windows are created.  You can prevent resizing in the *Matches* tab (*Non resizable windows* option) of the same plugin with similar matching rules (i. e. `class=whatever`).

The related and handy Place Windows plugin can be used to specify initial locations for windows.

[image: screenshot]

<sup>1</sup> Not installed by default. Install the `compizconfig-settings-manager` and `compiz-plugins-extra` packages. You need the second package as it gives the *Window Rules* option in Compiz.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Mozilla Firefox, you can also use the addon [Firesizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/5792/). It has a small menu where you can select the size or customize your settings:

[image: firesizer]

Comment: I didn't know I wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the lower right corner of your window and drag it. While you do this the dimension is shown and you can choose the exact size in pixels.

Comment: This depends on `compiz` running and the "Resize Info" plugin running, no?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't.

However for FireFox as part of the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) add on there is a window resize menu item for testing pages on different screen resolutions.

That resizes the FireFox window to an exact pixel size.

Answer (score 0):

For Nautilus you can also change the settings with `gconf-editor`. Go to apps -> nautilus -> preferences. On the right side there is an entry `navigation_window_saved_geometry`. Double-click on it and enter a number which fits you most.

Answer (score 0):

Many X applications also have a --geometry option that lets you specify the height/width and x/y position.  For instance:

gnome-terminal --geometry=114x40+1920+547

Another tool that can be used is 'wmctrl'.  This allows you to alter properties of already running windows, including position and size.  For instance:

chideok:~$ wmctrl -l -G | grep Possible

0x02339ca2  0 558  111  1216 1006 chideok Possible to limit the size of a window (such as a browser window) to exact pixel dimensions? - Ubuntu - Stack Exchange - Mozilla Firefox

chideok:~$ wmctrl -i -r 0x02339ca2 -e 0,100,100,100,100

chideok:~$ wmctrl -lG | grep Possible

0x02339ca2  0 110  146  100  100  chideok Possible to limit the size of a window (such as a browser window) to exact pixel dimensions? - Ubuntu - Stack Exchange - Mozilla Firefox